# NLog is writing to file but not to database table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, nlog

This is my NLog.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
          autoReload="true"
          throwExceptions="false"
          internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log" >

      <variable name="myvar" value="myvalue"/>

      <targets>

        <target name="database" xsi:type="Database"
                dbUserName="internwebuser"
                dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient"
                connectionStringName="SECURE"
                connectionString="Data Source=sqlservtest.starledger.com;Initial Catalog=SECURE;User ID=webuser;Password=password"
                commandText="insert into dbo.tracelog (custom_message, excep_message, insertdate) 
                values 
                (@custom_message, @excep_message, @insertdate);" >


          <parameter name="@custom_message"     layout="${exception}" />
          <parameter name="@excep_message"      layout="${exception:tostring}" />
          <parameter name="@insertdate"         layout="${date}" />


        </target>


        <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
                layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${callsite} from Line: ${callsite-linenumber} ${newline} 
    ${exception} ${newline}
    ${exception:tostring} ${newline}"
                fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}-${level}.log" />


      </targets>  

      <rules>

        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="database" />

      </rules>
    </nlog>
```

And my controller looks something like this:

```
public class ReportController : Controller
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try 
        {
            <!-- some statement -->
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error(e);
        }
        return View();
   }
}
```

This code writes perfectly into the file but the database table remains empty. Also, in my file, when I do it using `StreamWriter` and create a file instead of using NLog, the application writes 2/3 kinds of error into the file simultaneously. But NLog only writes the last error.

For example:

In case of `StreamWriter`, the errors are:

```
Exception Name:ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Exception Name:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

But In case of NLog, I only get:

```
Exception Name:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
and the first one is missed out.
```

My `StreamWriter` method looks like this:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

            string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

            string fileName = "error-log-" + today.Date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + ".txt";

            var file = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

            StreamWriter log;

            if (!File.Exists(file))
            {
                log = new StreamWriter(file);
            }

            else
            {
                log = File.AppendText(file);
            }

            // Write to the file:

            log.WriteLine("Data Time:" + DateTime.Now);    
            log.WriteLine("Exception Name:" + sExceptionName);    
            log.WriteLine("Event Name:" + sEventName);    
            log.WriteLine("Error Line No.:" + nErrorLineNo);    

            // Close the stream:

            log.Close();
```

and I pass the method into the `catch` section of my controller.

My main issue here is writing into the database table, although I'd appreciate help in writing all the errors too, using Nlog, instead of just the last one.

Comment: Please enable [internal logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) in order to have more info

Comment: Saw my error in the internal log! Thanks @MartinoBordin It is now writing to the database. Any idea on how to write all the errors instead of just the last one?

Comment: If I understand correctly your needs, you have to use an MVC Fillter. Take a look to [this implementation](https://github.com/MikeHanson/NLog.Mvc/wiki/Using-the-NLogMvcHandlEerrorAttribute)

Comment: Can i write my suggestion as answer, so you can set it as solved?

Comment: I actually had a typo in one of the column names, that's why it wasn't writing in the table. I used the internal log and found it! pretty embarrassing but yeah, thanks for suggesting about internal logging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please enable [internal logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) in order to have more info

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue.To find the exact issue I added `<nlog internalLogFile="c:\DemoLogs\nlog-internal.txt" and internalLogLevel="Error">` inside the nlog tag. which will write the exact proplem to a internal log file (nlog-internal.txt)

For my case `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient` was resolve by installing the required nuget package.